# The aerodynamic stability of the truncated cone shape

Tags: spacecraft, reentry, aerodynamics, aerobraking

Can someone explicate the stability of the truncated cone shape of the reentry vehicle of a spaceship when moving in the atmosphere with its bottom facing forward? It seems counterintuitive that it should be, since the most naive static force consideration would suggest the opposite. This naive consideration is best described by the setup of [this erroneous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/452893/17354). I did the force analysis in the comment below that answer and pointed out the error in the conclusion.

There are several questions [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6253/28835),[here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/11975/28835) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9062/28835) considering the cone shape of the reentry vehicle. However, even though the [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6258/28835) to the first question is most closely related to my concern, it does not address the aerodynamic stability.

Comment: The angle of the cone and the position of the center of mass may influence the aerodynamic stability and the orientation in the atmosphere.

Comment: @Uwe: Of course. The question is how.

Comment: Great question, could you tell more about this naive static force consideration ?

Comment: The Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry#Entry_vehicle_shapes referenced in the answer to https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/11975/reason-for-different-cone-angles-of-different-space-capsules?noredirect=1&lq=1 discusses this at a high level.  A spherical section with a cone is statically stable when the center of gravity is closer to the section than the center of curvature, and generates some lift.  The basic shape was chosen because it was amenable to closed-form computations.

Comment: @qqjkztd: I added the link to the naive static force analysis.

Comment: @antlersoft: That is one of the link in my question. It does not answer the question. However close the center of gravity is to the bottom section, it won't be stable.

Comment: You already post this question in physics and space exploration, I think it also deserves to be asked on mathematicSE and mostly aviationSE, since this is definitely a crossplatform one i guess, from geometric concerns to hypersonic, subsonic, and  scale related Reynolds numberish relevant one. I would do so for curiositys sake.

Comment: @qqjkztd: I agree, but I do not think it is appropriate for mathematics.SE since it is not a pure mathematics question.

Comment: If you already solved geometric instability/stability for both hollow and solid cone, where center of gravity is either H/3 or H/4, considering any angle relative to velocity vector, I also agree with you. Anyway I think it should be a good starting point before considering aerodynamic aspects, mostly drag coefficients.

Comment: @qqjkztd: Have you looked at my analysis of the answer on physics.SE? No matter where the center of mass is, the shape is statically unstable. If you put up a question on the aviation.SE, please put up a link here.

Comment: I think it is related to the square cube law. One large steel ball in freefall is less affected by drag than a small one. The cone can be assimilated to a small ball welded to a large one. the small one is a parachute for the big one.

Comment: @qqjkztd: I doubt that has much effect since the smaller vertex of the cone is in the slipstream of the bottom of the vertex. The stability of the cone in this orientation should be completely controlled by the bottom.

Comment: @Hans found [this](http://perso.numericable.fr/fbouquetbe63/gomars/stabilite_capsules_spatiales.pdf)

Comment: @qqjkztd: Very good. I was thinking along similar lines. The paper does not give any specifics though. I have presented a simple solution based on nothing more than the axial symmetry of the shape and the pressure being a decreasing function of the angle deviation from the incoming airflow direction. The surface norm needs only point behind the center of mass. Check it out.

Comment: This shape is properly known as a frustum.

Comment: @qqjkztd: Check out my answer again. It is correct, as supported by the hypersonic aerodynamic theory, JCRM's criticism notwithstanding.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'll note that if you drop a playing card to the floor edge-on, it will flip and tumble and go anywhere. But if you drop it broad-side down it will basically go straight down.

Comment: @Greg: We can qualitatively explain the behavior of your playing card example with simple aerodynamics. Particularly your playing card is a thin planar rectangle and thus no stability feedback when dropped edge-on. But I could not answer my question, at the beginning. I have figured out an answer since as posted below. Please read it.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition: We assume the following.

1) The force exerted by the air on a surface is pure pressure thus normal to the surface without friction. The pressure increases with respect to the magnitude of the surface normal component of the incident air flow velocity and is zero when the surface normal component becomes negative.

2) The surface of the capsule is axially symmetric. Label the intersection of the symmetric axis and the surface (bottom) facing the incoming airflow $B$. The inward normal vector $\vec n$ of any infinitesimal surface patch either intersects the axis at point $N$ some finite distance from $B$ or $\vec n$ parallels the axis. The center of mass of the capsule $C$ locates between $B$ and $N$.

The capsule achieves aerodynamic stability.

---

Before presenting the proof of this proposition, I give a plausible toy model of this air flow pressure function. The realistic function will surely be more complicated.

However, interestingly, two and a half months after I posted this answer, I happened upon the theory of hypersonic aerodynamics that surprisingly endorsed fully the following derivation as the correct computation for the pressure of hypersonic (Mach 3-5) airflow on an largely axial symmetric body with blunt surface geometry. c.f. equations (11-2) and (11-3) of [chapter 11 on the hypersonic aerodynamics](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~mason/Mason_f/ConfigAeroHypersonics.pdf) of [W. H. Mason's lecture on configuration aerodynamics](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~mason/Mason_f/ConfigAero.html). Search for "Newtonian Impact Theory" in [this accompanying PPT to that chapter](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~mason/Mason_f/HypersonicPres.pdf).

Suppose an air column of an infinitesimal cross section area $dA$ collide with a facet with its normal vector forming an angle $\theta\in\big[0,\frac\pi2\big]$ with the air flow direction vector. The air bounces off the facet completely elastically. The momentum change (all in the normal direction of the facet) per unit time is then $2\rho v^2\cos\theta dA$, where $\rho$ is the density of the air flow and $v$ the speed of it. The area upon which this momentum change occurs is $\frac{dA}{\cos\theta}$. Divide the first quantity by the second, we get the pressure $p(\theta):=2\rho v^2\cos^2\theta$. Now the early arriving particles bounce off of the surface normally and collide completely elastically with the late arriving particles and bounce back towards the surface again. By symmetry, the average particle velocity near the surface vanishes in the surface normal direction but its component tangent to the surface remains. Macroscopically, the fluid on average as a whole moves along the tangent of the surface. Alternatively we can assume the complete inelastic collision of the air molecule with the surface, so that the momentum normal to the surface completely dissipates only the tangential component is unmolested so the air molecules after the collision move parallel along the surface. In this case, it is clear $p(\theta):=\rho v^2\cos^2\theta$ which is half of the previous value as the surface normal momentum transferred is half of that in the elastic case. In the case of fractional elastic collision, the $p(\theta):=(1+\alpha)\rho v^2\cos^2\theta$ where $\alpha\in[0,1]$ is the coefficient of collision elasticity.

Moreover, the part of the object surface that is in the "shadow" of the incoming airflow will remain untouched by the airflow and thus experience no pressure.

---

Proof:

1) 2-dimension.

Let us formulate the problem formally. Let $s\in[-s_0,s_0],\,s_0>0$ measure the distance, with sign, from the intersection of the symmetry axis with the surface. Denote the unit inward normal vector at $s$ by $\hat n(s)$. Let $\theta(s)$ be the angle from $\hat n(0)$ to $\hat n(s)$ with counterclockwise direction as the positive direction for the angle. $\theta(-s)=-\theta(s)$ by the axial symmetry. Let the angle from $\hat n(s=0)$ to the incoming airflow direction be $\theta_a$ also with counterclockwise direction as the positive direction. Place the curve $(x(s),y(s))$ in the Cartesian coordinate such that $(x(s=0)=0,y(s=0)=0)$ and the center of mass be located at $(x=0,y=y_c)$. We have $(x(-s),y(-s))=(-x(s),y(s))$. Let $p(\beta)$ be the pressure as a function of the angle $\beta$ with respect to the incoming air flow. The torque at each curve with respect to $(0,y_c)$ is $l(s)p(\theta_a-\theta(s))$ where $l(s)\hat z = \big((x(s),y(s))-(0,y_c)\big)\times \hat n(s)$.

Without loss of generality we assume $\theta_a>0$. Otherwise we can just reflect the coordinate with respect to the $y$ axis and get back the same problem because of the axial symmetry.

The total torque is, needing to account for only the surface facing the incoming airflow, 
\begin{align}
T&:=\int_{-s_0}^{s_0}l(s)p(\theta_a-\theta(s))ds \\
&=\int_0^{s_0}l(s)\big(p(\theta_a-\theta(s))-p(\theta_a+\theta(s))\big)\,ds 
\end{align}
as $l(-s)=-l(s)$ by the axial symmetry of the curve. Stability is achieved if $T>0$. We have $l(s)>0,\,\forall s>0$ since, by Assumption 2), the center of mass $C$ located at $(0,y_c)$ is between $N$ (at the origin of the coordinate $(0,0)$) and $B$. $p(\theta_a-\theta(s))>p(\theta_a+\theta(s))$, since $|\theta_a-\theta(s)|<\theta_a+\theta(s),\ \forall \theta_a>0,\, \theta(s)>0,\, s>0$, and the fact that $p(u)>p(v),\,\forall |u|<|v|$. Therefore $T>0$.

QED

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89774/discussion-on-answer-by-hans-the-aerodynamic-stability-of-the-truncated-cone-sha).

Comment: My down-vote is because the reduction of the fields of sub-, trans-, super- and trans-sonic aerodynamics, and reentry gas effects to a one line assumption means this answer bears very little relevance to the real world. Beyond that, the proof boils down to the well understood statement "an object will be aerodynamically stable if the centre of pressure is behind the centre of mass"

Comment: @JCRM: You are right that the airflow, particularly the pressure it exerts on the surface of a body behaves differently in the regimes of sub-, trans-, super and hyper-sonic speeds. Fortunately, the assumption of my answer turns out to be correct in the hypersonic regime. The proposition, mathematically correct in the first place, is now very relevant to the geometry to achieve aerodynamic stability for the initial hypersonic reentry flight into the atmosphere. Please check out the edited second paragraph of the preamble to my proof. It contains the reference to the hypersonic aerodynamics.

Comment: The linked document does not "endorsed fully " your derivation, it talks about it being an approximation. section 11.16 and figure 11.20 partly explain why this is useless in a real-world scenario.

Comment: @JCRM: The linked equations are exactly the same as what I have derived. To what extent does the reference not "endorsed fully" my derivation? Your complaint of it being an approximation per se is a meaningless truism since no mathematical formula describing natural phenomena is not an approximation. Do you have one example that is an exception? There is no section 11.16. There is Section 11.6. How exactly and which part of that section and figure 11.20 explain Equation (11-3) is useless? Please write out the specific details of your logical derivation rather than traffic in vagueness.